# Problem understand integral of $1/(1+x^2)$ formula to solve integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integral of $dx/(1+4x^2)$

The formula is in x but the book says let 2x=x => x^2=(2x)^2 and the other be a^2 and puts it on formula integral of dx/a^2+x^2= 1/a tan^-1 (x/a)
[image: My solution]

[image: My solution]

What's wrong in steps underlined in green?
I divided up and down by 4 to get the formula in dx/1+x^2 form and when I just take 2x= X^2 and put in the formula dx/1+x^2 form the ans comes but when I divide up and down by 4 i do not get the ans

Comment: Please explain more clearly: what is the question; what is your attempt; why exactly are you confused.

Comment: I actually did a calculation error I multiplied a instead of dividing it. Sorry

Comment: Should I close the question

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question. Good opportunity to practice your [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I made a calculation error there the result of integral $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$ is $\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ instead of dividing by $a$ I multiplied $a$ and solved on $a \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$?which is clearly wrong

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2+b^2x^2=a^2+(bx)^2\longrightarrow bx=au$$
So,
$$1+4x^2\longrightarrow 2x=u$$
is the substitution you should make.

Then, we have $dx=\frac{du}{2}$,
$x=0\rightarrow u=0$, $x=a\rightarrow 
 u=2a$ and
$$\int_0^a\frac{dx}{1+4x^2}=\int_0^{2a}\frac{\frac{du}2}{1+u^2}\\
=\frac12\arctan(2a)=\frac\pi 8\implies a=\frac12.$$